# How do you create a bucket in Autodesk Forge Viewer? | Forge API

Tags: javascript, express, url-routing, autodesk-forge, autodesk

I am attempting to create and post a new bucket for the purpose of uploading and storing models. However, I consistently encounter a 400 Bad Request error. I previously had a backup project where, by some means, I was able to make it function correctly. Nevertheless, I now encounter the same error in that project as well.

In my routes folder the function to post a bucket is the following

```
router.post('/buckets', async (req, res, next) => {
    let payload = new PostBucketsPayload();
    payload.bucketKey = config.credentials.client_id.toLowerCase() + '-' + req.body.bucketKey;
    payload.policyKey = 'Persistent'; // Available until a user deletes the object.
    console.log('PAYLOAD: ', payload, '\nCLIENT: ', req.oauth_client, '\nTOKEN: ', req.oauth_token);
    try {
        await new BucketsApi().createBucket(payload, {}, req.oauth_client, req.oauth_token);
        res.status(200).end();
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

The Code in my tree.js looks like this:

```
function createNewBucket() {
  var bucketKey = $('#newBucketKey').val();
  jQuery.post({
    url: '/api/forge/oss/buckets',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'bucketKey': bucketKey }),
    success: function (res) {
      $('#userHubs').jstree(true).refresh();
      $('#createBucketModal').modal('toggle');
    },
    error: function (err) {
      if (err.status == 409)
        alert('Bucket already exists - 409: Duplicated')
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}
```

As already mentioned this has worked before and as you can see i printed the output of the values. None of them were undefined and looked fine. The only thing that I have changed is the callback URL  and my client secret/ID.

Im not very familiar with express basic routing, so if any crucial information is missing please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the callbacl url in your APS application as well?
Note:  The callback url should be the same in your APS app and code.

Comment: Yes, the callback url in my config is exactly the same as in my application settings on the autodesk website

Comment: Please use the new sample on viewer https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-simple-viewer-nodejs/blob/develop/services/aps.js